# How to show multiple rows associated with one ID if conditions in two fields are met

Tags: sql, oracle

I have entries in a table that are associated with a single ID number:

```
ID      TYPE         ENTITY_ID    Length(TRIM(Translate(entity_ID, ' +-.0123456789',' ')))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1111    Currency     EURO         4
1111    Issuer       355555       (null)
2222    State        WA           2
2222    Underwriter  Foo Inc      7
2222    Obligor      Alpha Assoc. 12
```

If the ID # has a type of either issuer or obligor AND the Entity_ID column of the associated row containing obligor or issuer IS NOT null, I want to show ALL of the rows associated with that ID number, not just the row/s that are not null.

This is my code for the above table so far:

```
Select ID, Type, Entity_Id, Length(TRIM(Translate(entity_ID, ' +-.0123456789',' '))) 
  from Meta_Detail where ID in( 1111, 2222)
```

With the conditions I stated above, both rows of 1111 would not show but all three rows of 2222 would.  How can I accomplish this? I am using Oracle SQL.

Thanks

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Strawberry Im not sure what youre saying with this link. Do I need to provide a more robust query? Data?

Comment: I think that the answer to that 'meta' question is fairly self-explanatory, but let me know if there's a specific point with which you're struggling.

Comment: Trying to explain the @Strawberry's suggestion, a [mcve] is a way to help people to better understand your need, build a test case and try some query to post a tested answer. In this case, something like `create table ...`, `insert into table ...`, 'the needed result is ...' would be great. This is however well described in the link he gave

Comment: Why wouldn't ID 1111 show? The entity_ID for the Issuer record in your sample data is not null, it's value is 355555.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Meta_Detail WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM Meta_Detail
WHERE (TYPE='Obligor' OR TYPE='Issuer' ) AND  ENTITY_ID IS NOT NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks!  Changing the ENTITY_ID to Length(TRIM(Translate(entity_ID, ' +-.0123456789',' '))) worked!